# I was seeing someone code , what is check(); that is used after every function?

Tags: javascript, function, web

I was seeing someone code , what is check(); that is used after every function ?

why in this code check(); function is called I think many times

```js
var a = 0;
var b = 0;
var c = 0;

function logo(c) {
  let nolo = document.getElementById('logo');
  nolo.setAttribute('src', "Office.jpg");
  golo = nolo.getAttribute('src');
  if (golo === "Office.jpg") {
    window.c = 2;
  }
  check();
}

function myflipkart(a) {
  let olo = document.getElementById('flipkart');
  olo.setAttribute('src', "Office.jpg");
  polo = olo.getAttribute('src');
  if (polo === "Office.jpg") {
    window.a = 2;
  }
  check();
}

function mybird(b) {
  let lo = document.getElementById('bird');
  lo.setAttribute('src', "Office.jpg");
  bolo = lo.getAttribute('src');
  if (bolo === "Office.jpg") {
    window.b = 2;
  }
  check();
}

function check() {
  if (a && b && c === 2) {
    console.log("Hello");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is checking if the three elements (logo, flipkart and bird) contain an image named "Office.jpg" in the src attribute.

What the function is doing is checking if the global variables a and b are true (i.e. different from 0) and if c is equal to 2.

In javascript when we check a variable with zero value, the return is false and any number above 0 is true.

Comment: I think they want to know WHY, not only WHAT.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The code is clumsy and has some mistakes

It seems to want to test if all functions to load images have been loaded and if they have, it will console.log hello

But this test is not testing what the writer intended.
It however still works by chance because 2 is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)

```
if (a && b && c === 2) {
  console.log("Hello");
}
```

Should either be

```
if (a === 2 && b === 2 && c === 2) {
  console.log("Hello");
}
```

OR use false and true instead of 0 and 2 and use

```
if (a && b && c) {
 console.log("Hello");
}
```

Also the getAttribute is a waste of time

```
nolo.setAttribute('src', "Office.jpg");
golo = nolo.getAttribute('src');
if (golo === "Office.jpg") { // ALWAYS true
```

Here is a shorter version doing the same and in a much more sensible way.

```js
const ids = ["logo","flipkart","bird"];
const setAndTest = (id,image) =>
  const img = document.getElementById(id);
  img.src = image;
  img.classList.add('done')
  if (document.querySelectorAll('img.done').length === ids.length) {
   console.log("Hello");
  }
};

// elsewhere

setAndTest("logo","Office.jpg");
setAndTest("flipkart","Office.jpg");
setAndTest("bird","Office.jpg");
```